# Disable double tap to zoom

Tags: javascript, safari, touch

Reasking because the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732074/disable-double-tap-zoom-on-safari-ios-13) aren't working for me.

Can the double-tap-to-zoom be disabled in the latest Safaris? I'm writing a game with a keyboard; people will hit the same key twice while typing fast. Obviously zooming is not appropriate in such a situation.

I've got

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

I've got

```
html, body, * { touch-action: manipulation }
```

I've got `style="touch-action: manipulation"` on the keys themselves.

Safari still zooms in iOS 15.

Is this fixable?

Comment: I think this solution will fix your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73334551/5818106